# Is there a way to see helpful information regarding event listeners in chrome/firefox developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Since I am binding to a click event with jQuery, it is really hard to figure out where that code is in my application.

The event listeners panel in chrome looks like this:

[image: chrome inspect event listeners panel]

However, when clicking on the definition, I am taken to jquery. There is no way to figure out which function was sent to jQuery, even if I blackbox the jquery script.

[image: chrome registered function in listeners panel]

In firefox developer edition is see something similar:

[image: firefox listeners panel]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug jQuery events using Firefox debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726269/how-do-i-debug-jquery-events-using-firefox-debugger)

Comment: @NoBugs, indded, looks like this is partially a duplicate. My question is for chrome in special, the only reason I mentioned firefox was because I didn't find that feature in chrome.